# java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation error

Tags: jboss, wildfly-8

I am getting this error in WildFly 8.2 at runtime:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.app.security.key.MyKeyRing.<init>(Lorg/app/security/key/MyPrivateKey;Lorg/app/security/key/MyPublicKey;[Ljava/security/cert/Certificate;)V" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of the current class, org/app/security/auth/KeyLoginModule, and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) for resolved class, org/app/security/key/MyKeyRing, have different Class objects for the type curity/key/MyPrivateKey;Lorg/app/security/key/MyPublicKey;[Ljava/security/cert/Certificate;)V used in the signature
```

The classes starts with 'My' are created for the application and is inside the EAR file. There is a custom module in created in WildFly and the jar with these classes are available in that too.

What may be the reason?

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you have two libraries with the same dependency on your class path.

Comment: Yeah, the class is in a jar file and that jar was added in EAR lib and in a custom module. When I removed dependency to this module, it worked.